# Bash Regex matches on Ubuntu but not on macOS

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

git_status="$(git status 2>/dev/null)"
branch_pattern="^(# |)On branch ([^${IFS}]*)"
echo $git_status
echo $branch_pattern

if [[ ${git_status} =~ ${branch_pattern} ]]; then
    echo 'hello'
    echo $BASH_REMATCH
fi
```

Here is the output when I run the script on Ubuntu with `bash` version 4:

```
On branch master Initial commit Untracked files: (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed) test.sh nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
^(# |)On branch ([^ ]*)
hello
On branch master
```

However, when I run the same script on macOS with bash version 3, the regex does not match, and nothing inside the `if` block is executed. The rest of the output is identical. What am I missing? Does my regex need to be formatted differently on macOS/in this version of bash? Is there a flag I am missing?

I have seen similar posts about differences in regex behavior across platforms for e.g., the `find` command, but I have not yet found a post relevant to my issue.

Comment: What is the desired result here? It seems you want just the current branch name (if any) ?

Comment: @Jebby yes basically. For the purposes of this question though, I would like to get the same result in the sample output from Ubuntu, but on macOS.

Comment: It might not be the RE, it might be `git`.  I just ran your script on OS X on 3.2 and on 4.4 and I got identical output, it did not find a match.  The reason is that `$git_status` is empty because it is failing  - take the `2> /dev/null` redirection off and you will see.

Comment: @cdarke interesting! But for me, `$git_status` is not empty on either platform. On both Ubuntu and macOS it gives me the expected status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like there's a bug in the RE engine in the version of bash that macOS comes with (it's rather old -- 3.2.57). It's something to do with the `^(# |)` part -- it doesn't seem to match an empty string at the beginning of the string, as it should. But I found a workaround. Apparently the bug doesn't happen if the `^` is inside the parentheses, like this:

```
branch_pattern="(^# |^)On branch ([^${IFS}]*)"
```

BTW, you shouldn't use `echo $varname` to print the contents of a variable. For one thing, it'll do word splitting (converting all runs of whitespace into single spaces) and wildcard expansion on the value, which can be very confusing/misleading. Try something like `printf '<<%q>>\n' "$varname"` instead. Its output can be a little cryptic if the variable contains weird characters, but at least it'll make it clear that there *are* weird things in there.

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm! Strange bug! Also, as far as using `echo`: the script where I am actually using this code does not use `echo`, that was for debugging purposes more than anything. The actual script adds something like`(master:+)` where `+` is a symbol representing the status of the working tree, to my bash prompt. I have been using it forever on Ubuntu, and now it is working on Mac! Nonetheless, the info about `echo` is useful too! I wasn't aware of the gotchas you pointed out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to get the current git branch name, there is no need for regex. Git already has this built in.

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null`

This will print out the current branch name (if any)
If you are in a git repository without any commits, it will only return "HEAD"

Comment: This is useful info, but what I am really trying to figure out is why the same regex does not match the same text across platforms.

Comment: Okay, my apologies. It has been some time since I have used a Mac, so I do not want to provide false information on that part. You do however say that you are running bash 3 on the Mac, and bash 4 on Ubuntu. Is it possible for you to upgrade bash, or is that out of the question?

Comment: I didn't look into upgrading bash, but the thought did occur to me. If it's even possible it is too big a risk for me since the computer in question is my work computer, and I don't want to risk messing up my dev environment. Luckily, the accepted answer above worked for me! I may refactor my script to use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null` though!